# Download file using regex in wget

Tags: curl, download, wget

I have files at remote location, name looks like:

```
ranjans-vra_test1-standalone-6ff194f94-0.vraCafe.0-nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json
```

The unique words can be `test1` `vraCafe` and `nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json` . I am trying to download the file using `wget` command:

```
wget -r http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/.*test1.*vraCafe.*nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json -O /usr/nimbus/testbeds/vra/vra.json
```

I am getting `404` error. What modification should I do in my command?

Comment: curl will also work for me! Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of achieving that with only the wget command, since you can't download the entire internet with `wget *.*`.

If you know the name of the files you can paste them into a `urls.txt` file:

```
http://URL/foo/bar.json
http://URL/foo/baz.json
```

Then call `wget -i urls.txt`

Comment: My problem I don't have exact file name. I only have pattern. Any other script like curl is also fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below command work for me:

```
wget -r --no-parent -I /ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds -X /ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/nimbusUtilStats -A "*test1*vraCafe.0-nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json" http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/ -P ${WORKSPACE}/nimbus
```

The only problem here I am facing is: it is downloading with full url and file name. Need to find out a solution with `wget` or it can be resolve by writing some shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Solution with wGET:

```
for i in $(wget -qO- http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/ | grep "*test1.*vraCafe.*nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json<" | awk '{split($0,file,"\""); print file[2]}'); do curl -O http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/$i; done
```

Solution with cURL:

```
for i in $(curl http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/ | grep "*test1.*vraCafe.*nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json<" | awk '{split($0,file,"\""); print file[2]}'); do curl -O http://URL/ranjans/testbeds/vra/testbeds/$i; done
```

Thus, all files that satisfy the regex `*test1.*vraCafe.*nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json` will be downloaded.